# how to setup a unittest for a web-project

Tags: unit-testing, dart, dart-editor

I have problems to properly configure my first unittest in the DartEditor(1.8.5).

I wrote a web-app with Dart that is located in the web-folder.
Now i added a test-folder parallel to web with a file called `test.dart`:

```dart
library dartingflame_test;

import 'dart:math';
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import 'package:unittest/html_config.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import '../web/dartingflame.dart';

void main() {
  useHtmlConfiguration();

  test("verify robot's direction after move", verifyRobotDirectionAfterMove);
}

void verifyRobotDirectionAfterMove() {...}
```

Unfortunatly I now have problems to run this test file.

- **Run with Dartium** leads to the message: `Unable to locate associated html file`
- **Run** leads to: `Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:49919
  The built-in library 'dart:html' is not available on the stand-alone VM.
  'package:unittest/html_config.dart': error: line 10 pos 1: library handler failed
  import 'dart:html';`

Using `useVMConfiguration()` instead of `useHtmlConfiguration()` doesn't help. The test execution still complaints about the `import 'dart:html';`-line in the library under test.

I couldn't find a solution in the ["Unit Testing with Dart"](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests/)-article.

**UPDATE (incorporating Günter Zöchbauer's comment)**

ok, i created the index.html which invokes test.dart, but now i seem to have a problem with the relative import of the lib under test `import '../web/dartingflame.dart';`:

```dart
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8081/web/dartingflame.dart
An error occurred loading file: http://localhost:8081
```

Comment: If you want to test code the code should be in `lib` not in `web` then you can use package import instead of relative import.

Comment: my app contains many domain objects that paint on the canvas. In order to move those to lib to the lib-folder, i'd have to abstract from `CanvasRenderingContext2D` which is a parameter in their repaint-methods. While this is possible it seems to be overkill. And there has to be a way to test stuff in the web-folder, otherwise the `unittest/html_config.dart` file wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about "... have to abstract form `CanvasRenderingContext2D`" and `unittest/html_config.dart`. I can't see a reason why the place of the code would have any influence regarding this topics. There is no reason to have code in `web`. The only thing that needs to be in web is the entry page HTML file with the Dart script tag (containing main). Importing files from outside a top-level directory (`web`, `bin`, `example`, `test`, ...) besides `lib` is usually just wrong. When you use relative import always stay inside the top-level dir you are in otherwise use package.

Comment: ah, so the problem with testing my web code is not that the code imports `dart:html`, but that the code lies under `web`?!

Comment: I still don't see how the folder where your code is in is related to whether you have to abstract or whether it imports dart:html. The only thing that changes are the paths in the import statements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a web page `index.html` with the test script as script tag an launch it like any Dart web app. You can also run it non-interactively using `content_shell`. The Dart SDK contains a batch script which downloads and installs `content_shell` (it is left out of the SDK download to keep a reasonable download size.

There is also a package `test_runner` available at http://pub.dartlang.org which helps running all tests in the `test` directory.